# Strange jQuery behaviour with bxSlider - not giving me an integer value in a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, bxslider

I'm using the jQuery plugin called bxSlider. There is a function of this slider called `goToSlide` which should put the slider to a specific slide. I'm having problems getting this to work and experiencing some strange behaviour.

Here is my code:

```
function changeSlideAfterChangeImage(currentlySelected) {
var currentImageIndex = $('*[data-thumb-image-id="'+currentlySelected+'"]').parent().data("slide-index");

$('.active-slide').removeClass('active-slide');
thisBxSlider.goToSlide( parseInt(currentImageIndex) );

}
```

The variable `currentImageIndex` is giving me the correct value such a '5' but the slider is just sits on the last slide all the time.

Now for the strange behaviour....

If I specifically set `currentImageIndex` the slider goes to that slide all the time (i.e. works correctly).

```
function changeSlideAfterChangeImage(currentlySelected) {
var currentImageIndex = 5; // THIS WORKS

$('.active-slide').removeClass('active-slide');
thisBxSlider.goToSlide( parseInt(currentImageIndex) );

}
```

Also, if I increment the currentImageIndex then the slider changes and goes to the slide next to the correct one.

```
function changeSlideAfterChangeImage(currentlySelected) {
var currentImageIndex = $('*[data-thumb-image-id="'+currentlySelected+'"]').parent().data("slide-index");
currentImageIndex = currentImageIndex + 1; // THIS WORKS CORRECTLY IN THAT IT GOES TO THE SLIDE *AFTER* TO THE CORRECT ONE

$('.active-slide').removeClass('active-slide');
thisBxSlider.goToSlide( parseInt(currentImageIndex) );

}
```

However, if I then do this....

```
function changeSlideAfterChangeImage(currentlySelected) {
var currentImageIndex = $('*[data-thumb-image-id="'+currentlySelected+'"]').parent().data("slide-index");
currentImageIndex = currentImageIndex + 1; 
currentImageIndex = currentImageIndex - 1; // THIS DOESN'T WORK - THE SLIDER JUST SITS ON THE LAST SLIDE 

$('.active-slide').removeClass('active-slide');
thisBxSlider.goToSlide( parseInt(currentImageIndex) );

}
```

Nor does this work...

```
function changeSlideAfterChangeImage(currentlySelected) {
var currentImageIndex = $('*[data-thumb-image-id="'+currentlySelected+'"]').parent().data("slide-index");
currentImageIndex = currentImageIndex + 1; 
var tryAnotherVar = currentImageIndex - 1; // THIS DOESN'T WORK - THE SLIDER JUST SITS ON THE LAST SLIDE 

$('.active-slide').removeClass('active-slide');
thisBxSlider.goToSlide( parseInt(tryAnotherVar) );

}
```

I'm completely stumped.. any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this issue (after a lot of investigation) was to do with the order that the slider was being created and the command to ask it to go to a specific slide.

It seemed that I was asking it to go to a specific slide before it was fully working. Hence, when I had put 'alerts' into the code to debug certain situations then it worked because the alert must have given the slider time to initialise etc.

Sorted now.... another x number of hours of my life I'll never get back. Ever wonder why we pour our lives into a computer instead of sitting outside in the sunshine like the rest of them??

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be not an issue with the slider but the value of *currentImageIndex*.

- If value is out of range (e.g. if you have 5 slides 0..4 then you cannot go to slide #5 because index is zero based and last slide is #4) This is not about your particular example, just a general idea why it might not work.
- the value is not an integer

  This can be easily checked if you change

  ```
  var currentImageIndex = 5; // THIS WORKS
  ```

  to

  ```
  var currentImageIndex = '5';
  ```

  You will see that it will work too. So I suppose that the value of `$('*[data-thumb-image-id="'+currentlySelected+'"]').parent().data("slide-index")` is differ from 5 (maybe it includes special characters, etc)

As for the other example

```
currentImageIndex = currentImageIndex + 1; 
currentImageIndex = currentImageIndex - 1; // THIS DOESN'T WORK - THE SLIDER JUST SITS ON THE LAST SLIDE
```

it's easy: adding 1 and subtracting 1 equals to the same value.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I've console logged the value in currentImageIndex and it doesn't contain any special characters? Also the value that is being set is within range of the slides I have. I'm going to do some more investigation on this later. Will post back if I find anything... :-)